# What are rules for off-handed weapons?

Tags: exalted-3e

We just played Exalted 3 last night and one of our characters had 2 weapons (a main and an off-hand). We could find reference to several charms that affected/removed the "off-hand penalty" but could not actually figure out what the off-hand penalty was in the first place.

Are there rules for fighting with off-hand weapons, and if so what/where are they?

Answer (score 3):

**You suffer a -1 Penalty to attacks with the Off-Hand**

Locating this was not straight forward because the information was not where I would have expected it to be. But, I don't have the final release version of the rulebook with me; I put this together from the In-Dev version that I do have with me. So, the final version of the Exalted 3 rulebook may have this oversight corrected and put the penalty in the correct place, with the normal rules for Dual-Wielding.

First, we have the normal rules for Dual-Wielding

> Characters can wield one weapon in each hand as long as both weapons
>   lack the two-handed tag. Even with a weapon in each hand, characters
>   can still only make a single attack on each turn. However, if the
>   character is wielding a different weapon in each hand, she is free to
>   choose between the weapons and their associated tags each time she
>   attacks or parries, and may stunt her attacks and defenses however she
>   wants, as with a Crane stylist defending with her hook sword’s Parry
>   value while describing her blocks as performed with her war fan.
>   Characters who dual-wield two identical weapons gain a +2 bonus to
>   Clash attacks. “Unarmed” is considered a single weapon.

But this doesn't specify any sort of modifier to using your offhand weapon. However, if we look in Merits, we see this:

> Ambidextrous (• or ••)—Innate The character doesn’t suffer a -1
>   penalty to actions using his off-hand.

This clearly implies that attacks using your off-hand suffer a -1 Penalty, by stating that you don't take said penalty.

Comment: As an aside: This makes sense given the 'Martial Penalties' listed on p188. Things like "poor lighting" or "slick terrain" impose a -1 modifier. Things like "fighting blind" or "fighting while balancing on a rope" imposes a -3 modifier. Fighting with your offhand is much more comparable to poor lighting/slick terrain than it is to blindfighting

Comment: Update: The final version does not identify what are off-hand penalties anywhere other than the Ambidextrous and Tail merits.